# Tag each line of array inside a { symbol

Tags: equations, align, labels, arrays, tags

I want to tag each line of an array that is inside the { symbol. For the example bellow I use *align*, but a solution with *equation, subequation* or some other "top" structure might also work.

Here is an example:

```
\begin{align}
\mathbf{S} = \left\{ \begin{array}{lll}
a & \text{name a} \\
b & \text{name b} \\
c & \text{name c}, 
\end{array} \right.
\end{align}
```

I would like to have number-letter tag for each line of this structure, i.e. (1a), (1b) and (1c) for example.

Comment: Welcome! *Where* do you want to have these tags? At the right margin or at the right of  the matrix (like a bordered matrix)?

Comment: At the right margin, as the "normal equation" tags that I can refer to through the text. By default, Latex assigns single equation number to the whole expression above.

Comment: I recommend the `empheq` solution to the question marked for duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate a `Bmatrix` environment with `empheq` and `alignat` and use the `subequations` environment. You don't have to load `amsath`, as `ampheq` loads `mathtools`, which is an extension of `amsmath`. For single left brace, the simplest is the `subnumcases` environment:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq, cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{empheq}[left={\mathbf{S} = \empheqlbrace}, right=\empheqrbrace]{alignat = 2}
    a &\hspace{2\arraycolsep} & & \text{name a} \\
    b & & & \text{name b} \\
    c & & & \text{name c},
  \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subnumcases}{\mathbf{S} = }
        a & \text{name a} \\
        b & \text{name b} \\
        c & \text{name c},
\end{subnumcases}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think the right brace is wanted: the OP has `\right.`

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the answer I needed!
The right brace is not needed, but it is not central to my problem.

Comment: I don't know why I thought you wanted a *pair* of braces. For a single left brace, you can use the `cases` package: it defines a `subnumcases` environment. I'll add it in a moment

Comment: It is possible to have single brace inside your code as well, I simply removed "\empheqrbrace" after "right=".

Comment: You even can remove `right=`: neither `left=` nor `right=` are mandatory.